Movie about an army platoon propelled back to the American Civil War
I watched this movie in the 1980s.
The story is that a present-day US army platoon is propelled back into the days of the American Civil War. This modern platoon carried the same regimental number as an actual platoon from the Civil War, that was responsible for some atrocities in the very region the modern platoon found itself.
The leader of the platoon was a women and I can recall seeing a young boy crossing a field (maybe a battlefield) toward the end of the movie.
Now, the dead are seeking revenge.

"The dead are seeking revenge". Are there zombies or something? That seems like it would be pretty relevant to mention.

Are you sure it was a movie? Did you see it on TV or video? Do you have any other details?

I saw it on video. I do not recall if they were zombies, but I believe that the dead were more ordinary like.

The Supernaturals, 1986
From wikipedia:  

One hundred years ago, deep in the sullen backwoods of the Southern United States, a Confederate town is held captive, the soldiers forced to walk through a piece of woodland laced with mines. [...] Jump to circa 1985 and a platoon of soldiers are out on manouevres in the same backwoods. They too are the 44th, descendants of the Union platoon of years before, those who committed the atrocities. [...] During the night, an eerie fog rolls in, encompassing the 44th, and the Confederate Dead close in on their camp. Most of the 44th are subsequently killed [...]

The difference being that the platoon is not traveling back in time.

Sounds a bit like the classic Twilight Zone episode The 7th Is Made Up of Phantoms.  It's about a then modern platoon that wanders into the battle of little big horn.
It has some differences to your description though:

It's from the 60's, not the 80's. 
The soldiers join the battle willingly, so no ghosts out for revenge. 
It's the wrong war being fought.


I have no doubt of the Civil War content of the movie.
